# NGXS action type

Tags: angular, ngxs, typescript-decorator

I'm wondering why there's no decorator for defining the action type string, instead of declaring a static constant/variable each time you declare an action name.

I though about something like this:

```
function ActionType(type: string) {
  return (ctor: Function) => {
    ctor.type = type;
  }
}

@ActionType('Hello World !')
class MyAction {

}
```

I'm not sure if adding `type` to the constructor is equivalent to a static member, but I do know that after using the decorator, `console.log(MyAction.type)` would print `Hello World !` as it would if we declared a static member.

Would that work ?

Comment: Why you want to have type as static field instead of attribute?

Comment: That's what I've seen in all the NGXS tutorials. I'm new to NGXS, or more accurately, am still considering whether to use it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're lookng fo r something like this:

```js
function decorate(typ: string) {
  return function <T extends {new (...args) }>(cls: T): T & { type: string } {
    return class extends cls { 
      static type: string = typ;
    }
  }
}
@decorate("")
class Foo {
    static bar() {
        return 42
    }
}

Foo.type // ''
```

Weird parts:

`(arg: T)` means that arg is instance of T class. `arg: { new (...args): T}` means that arg is class T (not a instance)

`&` operator is merge types from two interfaces e.g. `{ key1: string } & { key2: number }` is equal `{ key1: string, key2: number }`

`return class extends cls` means we return anonymous class that extends `cls` (in that case `Foo`). We're adding static type: string to it because we forced that by `T & { type: string }` part

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20decorate(typ%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20function%20%3CT%20extends%20%7Bnew%20(...args)%20%7D%3E(cls%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20cls%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20type%3A%20string%20%3D%20typ%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%40decorate(%22%22)%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2042%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Looks good, but the real question is whether this will do the job with regards to NGXS action types ? In other words, would that enable me to get rid of the static member for each action type ?

Comment: Yes, this decorator don't know anything about ngxs because he don't have to. Ngxs required from you class with static method and you can create it by defining `class Action { static type: string` or y decorator. Value and type definition will be the same.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't NGSX come with built-in decorator like this ? After all, it is full of decorators all over the place and it's much better at making sure the action types are defined correctly

Comment: To be honest: I don't know. I'm using ngrx where type is not static, ant they are guarded by `Action` interface. I'm thinking that decorator is not necessary because creating class with decorator or with static attribute is the same amount o LoC.

Comment: I'm actually interested in doing more work inside the decorator (registering the action to a name->action map) which I'm missing in NGXS. Don't you find NGRX tedious in terms of the amount of boilerplate code it makes you write ?

Comment: Tried this to test out NGXS in our project, turned out that this breaks type constraint on the Action class (I get a message like "action class has to have a string field named 'type'" when I use it in NGXS' Action decorator).